# linux + why command output cant be filter or can saved in file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, redhat-enterprise-linux, ntp

`clockdiff` is command that measure clock difference between hosts

here is example from my Linux machine.

```
clockdiff -o 162.23.2.2
.
host=server11 rtt=750(187)ms/0ms delta=0ms/0ms Tue Oct 24 11:01:42 2023
```

the problem is when we want to filter the output or save the output to file as the following

```
clockdiff -o 162.23.2.2 >/tmp/file

more /tmp/file

1698145574 0 0
```

as we can see above the output from file isn't the output as we run the command from console

any ideas how to save the output as the following:

```
.
host=server11 rtt=750(187)ms/0ms delta=0ms/0ms Tue Oct 24 11:01:42 2023
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if the required output is going to stderr?

Comment: Try `clockdiff -o 162.23.2.2 >/tmp/file 2>&1`

Comment: already did it as clockdiff -o 162.23.2.2 2>/tmp/file  , but /tmp/file is empty

Comment: I also try the clockdiff -o 162.23.2.2 >/tmp/file 2>&1 , but from /tmp/file we can see only that --> 698146203 0 0

Comment: just one note we have RHEL 7.9 server

Comment: just to be clear the /tmp/file include the number as --> 698146203 0 0 and not the original output.

Comment: Are you by chance writing to `/tmp/file` from another process? Try writing to `/tmp/foooo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clockdiff` detects if its stdout is a terminal device or not, it formats its output differently in these both cases. This is similar to the behavior of tools that e.g. automatically color their output to a terminal, but omit color codes when writing to a pipe or to a regular file (e.g. GNU `ls` with `--color=auto`). The behavior of `clockdiff` is similar in mechanics, but quite insane; as you have discovered, it's far beyond "cosmetics", the outputs in the two cases differ greatly.

The (mis)feature is not (or not yet) documented; or at least I haven't found it documented. If there is an option to turn the (mis)feature off, it's not documented either.

Ignore all comments and hypotheses that suspect stderr or some problem with the file you redirected to. I have tested `clockdiff` from `iputils 20221126` in my Debian 12, its behavior depends *solely* on stdout being a terminal or not.

To save what you see in the terminal to a regular file, you need to trick `clockdiff`. Please read [*How to trick a command into thinking its output is going to a terminal*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/249723/108618). The link leads to an established question on our sister site; if it ever breaks, it will break along with the whole Stack Exchange (including Super User), so there is no need to repeat everything here. Below there's a list of possible tools gathered from selected answers to the linked question. See those answers for details.

Possible tools:

- [`ptybandage`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249801/108618)
- [`unbuffer`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249737/108618) – this I have tested with `clockdiff`, it is a solution:

  ```
  unbuffer clockdiff -o 162.23.2.2 >/tmp/file
  ```
- [`script`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249726/108618) – also tested, it is a solution (but `script` will add a header and a footer to the file; and even its (echoed) input, so taking input from `</dev/null` is a good idea):

  ```
  </dev/null script -qc 'clockdiff -o 162.23.2.2' -O /tmp/file
  ```
- [`socat` with `pty` option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249764/108618) – this I have also tested, it is a solution:

  ```
  socat -u EXEC:'clockdiff -o 162.23.2.2',pty STDOUT >/tmp/file
  ```
- [custom shared library used with `LD_PRELOAD`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/273412/108618) – also tested, it is a solution (and note if you want `sudo clockdiff …` then `LD_PRELOAD=… sudo clockdiff …` probably won't work, while `sudo LD_PRELOAD=… clockdiff …` may work; but all this depends on the policy).

Notes:

- Most of these tools "trick a command into thinking its output is going to a terminal" by *actually* connecting its output to a pseudoterminal created solely for this purpose. The command is not tricked, it gets a terminal. The `LD_PRELOAD` trick is the one that really tricks. It makes the command "think" its output is going to a terminal, without providing a terminal. A tricked command may misbehave when it tries to do something to the "terminal" that's not a terminal (e.g. the command unexpectedly gets `Inappropriate ioctl for device`); but `clockdiff` in my tests behaved well.
- Some of these tools automatically connect stderr of the command to the same destination as stdout, so the two streams get merged (in your case they both go to `/tmp/file`). `socat` and the `LD_PRELOAD` trick allow you to easily tell stdout and stderr of `clockdiff` apart.